# Firing Foundation 6 tab from multiple links

Tags: tabs, zurb-foundation-6

Is there a way to pull up a tab from a second link to that tab?

I have two tabs, the links inside the tabs-title work, but I want to include another link to tab 2 inside the tab-panel area of tab 1 - and vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little javascript. Add this anchor to the content of tab 1 to open tab 2.

`<a href="#" onclick="$('#example-tabs').foundation('selectTab', '#panel2');">Open Tab 2</a>`

Here is an example using the tabs docs with panel choosers added.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
                <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
            <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
                <p><a href="#" onclick="$('#example-tabs').foundation('selectTab', '#panel2');">Open Tab 2</a></p>
                <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
                <p><a href="#" onclick="$('#example-tabs').foundation('selectTab', '#panel1');">Open Tab 1</a></p>
                <p>Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus.  Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor.  Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Zurb Foundation 6 selectTab method doc: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html#selecttab